# Adding PImage to an ArrayList of PImage using filenames from a text file?

Tags: arraylist, processing

So what I'm trying to do is receive the name of a text file that contains a list of filenames of a sequence of images that I have stored in a separate folder. So I get the path to the actual image files using a scanner and scan through each line of the text file, therefore reading the names of the image files in the context of their actual location. Note that the text file and folder of the images have the same path. My question is how do I get these images into my ArrayList of PImages so I can then later load and display them sequentially in a repeating loop using draw()?

```
private List <PImage> myImage;
private int myFrameRate, myImageNumber;
private Boolean myRunningStatus;

public AnimationPanel(String path, String textFilename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    myImage = new ArrayList <PImage>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path + textFilename));
    myFrameRate = 20;
    myRunningStatus = true;
    myImageNumber = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        loadImage(path + scanner.nextLine());
        myImageNumber++;
    }
    scanner.close();
}


public void play() {
    myRunningStatus = true;
}

public void pause() {
    myRunningStatus = false;
}

public void setup() {
    size(300, 200);
    frameRate(myFrameRate);
}

public void draw() {
    background(255);
    if(myRunningStatus == true){
        image(myImage.get(myImageNumber), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (untested)

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    PImage p = loadImage(path + scanner.nextLine());
   myImage.add(p);
}
```